# Easier way to check if an item from one list of tuples doesn't exist in another list of tuples in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have two lists of tuples, say,

```
list1 = [('item1',),('item2',),('item3',), ('item4',)] # Contains just one item per tuple
list2 = [('item1', 'd',),('item2', 'a',),('item3', 'f',)] # Contains multiple items per tuple

Expected output: 'item4' # Item that doesn't exist in list2
```

As shown in above example I want to check which item in tuples in list 1 does not exist in first index of tuples in list 2. What is the easiest way to do this without running two for loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your tuple structure is exactly as shown above, this would work:

```
tuple(set(x[0] for x in list1) - set(x[0] for x in list2))
```

or per @don't talk just code, better as set comprehensions:

```
tuple({x[0] for x in list1} - {x[0] for x in list2})
```

result:

```
('item4',)
```

Comment: Why not set comprehensions?

Answer (score 0):

This gives you `{'item4'}`:

```
next(zip(*list1)) - dict(list2).keys()
```

The `next(zip(*list1))` gives you the tuple `('item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4')`.

The `dict(list2).keys()` gives you `dict_keys(['item1', 'item2', 'item3'])`, which happily offers you set operations like that set difference.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc@xDoIwEMbxvU/xJQ5tDZoADi5MPoZxIFLjKZSmPRLx5WuBQXH7J5f@7upGvve2PDofY0uBc1Q4K0lsulxmOluy@GY5JZY@pL5gg1NvuSYb8BgCo7cG0xTOePDgWiMmuVjJkM2Kh6xXOyBv/3g3tExJm/HwowtvQpol35oXqzc5tZ3/ojV2aOjKaj5A759mDEoL4TxZVsszHeMH)

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I can think of doing it, not sure if it helps though. I removed the commas in the items in `list1` because I don't see why they are there and it affects the code.

```
list1 = [('item1'),('item2'),('item3'), ('item4')] # Contains just one item per tuple
list2 = [('item1', 'd',),('item2', 'a',),('item3', 'f',)] # Contains multiple items per tuple
not_in_tuple = []

OutputTuple = [(a) for a, b in list2]
for i in list1:
    if i in OutputTuple:
        pass
    else:
        not_in_tuple.append(i)

for i in not_in_tuple:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have a choice but to loop over the two lists. Once efficient way could be to first construct a set of the first elements of list2:

```
items = {e[0] for e in list2}
list3 = list(filter(lambda x:x[0] not in items, list1))
```

Output:

```
>>> list3
[('item4',)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `set.difference`:

```
>>> set(next(zip(*list1))).difference(dict(list2))
{'item4'}
>>>
```

Or even better:

```
>>> set(list1) ^ {x[:1] for x in list2}
{('item4',)}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

that is a difference operation for sets:

```
set1 = set(j[0] for j in list1)
set2 = set(j[0] for j in list2)
result = set1.difference(set2)
```

output:

```
{'item4'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in list1:
  a=i[0]
  for j in list2:
      b=j[0]
      if a==b:
          break
  else:
      print(a)
```